# Make Customer Email Field Unique

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

is there a way to make the account email unique in Acumatica Customer?
I already tried the Duplication Validation in Customer Managements Preference but it seems that it doesn't work on Customer.

I am thinking if it can be done on Customization Project, though I have still no idea on that part.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution will be to add the `PXUniqueAttribute` to the email field like below:

```
public class CR_Contact_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Contact>
{
    #region EMail  
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXUnique]
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

This change will result in the below error message on persist. But please note that the field itself is part of the contact record, so by doing this you are affecting also all the contacts.
[image]

Comment: Hi Samvel, thanks a lot for this one!. It is working on my side now.